# How to detect the screen the JavaFx app window is on and show dialogs there?

Tags: javafx

I've a JavaFx app which shows some alerts/dialogs, but in the multi-screen environment, when the app is moved to a secondary screen, those alerts/dialogs are still shown on the primary screen.

How can I (automatically) show those (non-modal) dialogs on the same screen the app is on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to set the owner of your dialog:

`dialog.initOwner(primaryStage)`

And make sure you don't call it before `primaryStage.show()`

To detect on which screen the app is showing, you can use the bounds of the primary screen:

```
private boolean isOnPrimaryScreen(double x) {
    Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
    return x <= bounds.getMaxX();
}
```

Comment: The `initOwner` (and `owner` for ControlFx) work as expected, thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't your `isOnPrimaryScreen` return false positive if both/all screens are of same dimensions? :o

Comment: Calling stage.getX() when the stage is on the second screen, will add the x coordinates to the width of the primary screen

Answer (score 1):

My non-primary screens are to the left of my primary screen, so their bounds have negative `minX` values. A stage on one of these screens will have a negative `x` value, so the method in the accepted answer will incorrectly return `true`. I use the `Screen.getScreensForRectangle` method. That method can potentially return more than one screen for an arbitrary rectangle, so I use code like the following when I only care about the upper left corner of my stage:

```
/**
 * Returns the screen for the specified stage.
 *
 * @param stage the stage
 * @return the screen for the specified stage
 */
@Nonnull
public static Screen getScreenForStage(@Nonnull Stage stage) {
    for (Screen screen : Screen.getScreensForRectangle(stage.getX(), stage.getY(), 1., 1.)) {
        return screen;
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Cannot determine screen for stage.");
}
```